# Change the width of the <p> tag's content but not to change the width's of elements there

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

The problem is with WordPress post editing. I have a `p` tag which has some text and images in it.

I want the text to be 50% width of the p and the image to be able to take the full width of the p.

Is it possible and how? (By default each image is placed into the p tag)

```html
<p>
  Here is some text which i want to have the 50% width of the p.
  <img src="">
</p>
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I can't see any code. :(

Comment: bootstrap will make your life easy.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @3rdthemagical added the code

Comment: @xpuc7o added the code

Comment: Is there a reason the image has to be embedded in the `<p>`?

Comment: @hungerstar this is wordpress post content. So the images are placed into the <p>. Am I able to change it's structure?

Comment: and why did you tag php? and wordpress?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile because I bumped into this problem in wordpress. I'm editing the post and the images are placed into the p tag.

Comment: <img src="..." width="100%"> will do the image resize you want.

Comment: Apparently an internet search was not performed, a more proper solution can be [found here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7090/stop-wordpress-wrapping-images-in-a-p-tag).

Comment: @hungerstar thanks for your help! This is more proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by padding your paragraph by 50% and then making your image double the width of the remaining space:

```css
p {
  padding-right:50%;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-top:1em;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum in massa magna. Mauris a dui porttitor, tempus eros quis, efficitur est. Nam mollis auctor tempor. Phasellus ultrices porta gravida. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per
  conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed rutrum vitae leo et venenatis. Ut consectetur sem in turpis tincidunt, sit amet vestibulum arcu volutpat. Aliquam tristique nulla vel scelerisque feugiat. Phasellus sodales diam nec leo pretium, ac placerat
  sem faucibus. Vivamus congue sapien hendrerit urna imperdiet, vel efficitur ipsum mollis.
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Full%20Width&w=500&h=300">
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex;` like this.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
h1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
/*play with these values*/

img {
  flex-grow: 3;
}
/*play with these values*/
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>x</h1>
  <img src="http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg">
</div>
```

Where parent is parent element and child, child2 are children elements

You should set display:flex to your parent element and flex-grow to equal numbers(if you want both of them to be 50% width)

Some documentation:

[FLEXBOX](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Of course you can use different technique using CSS or even JavaScript but I think this one is the easiest one

Answer (score 0):

If your `img` must be inside the `p` (not ideal), here's an alternative to flexbox etc.:

```
p {
  padding-right: 50%;
}
p img {
  width: 200%;
  max-width: 200%;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kn1ctyqk/